# Wrong values in a column of dataframe with R

Tags: r

I have this problem since three days now and I hope so much to find someone who can help me to find a solution :

To do a sentiment analysis of a text, I store i a dataframe a list of words and their positive and negative polarities:

```
 word         positive.polarity       negative.polarity 
1 interesting                 1                 0                          
2      boring                 0                 1
```

then, for each word of those words in the dataframe, I would like to know if in their context ( context is a set of 3 words preceding the word) there is a booster word or a negation word :

```
-booster_words <- c("more","enough", "a lot", "as", "so")
-negative_words <- c("not", "rien", "ni", "aucun", "nul", "jamais", "pas", "non plus", "sans")
```

I would like to create a new column positive.ponderate.polarity which contains positive polarity value + 4 if there in a booster and negative word in the context, andpositive polarity value + 9 if there is only booster word in the context (there is no negative word in context).

Here is the code :

```
calcPolarity <- function(sentiment_DF,sentences){
     booster_words <- c("more","enough", "a lot", "as", "so")
     negative_words <- c("not", "rien", "ni", "aucun", "nul", "jamais", "pas", "non plus", "sans")
     reduce_words <- c("peu", "presque", "moins", "seulement")
     # pre-allocate the polarity result vector with size = number of sentences
     polarity <- rep.int(0,length(sentences))

     # loop per sentence
     for(i in 1:length(polarity)){
         sentence <- sentences[i]

         # separate each sentence in words using regular expression 
        wordsOfASentence <- unlist(regmatches(sentence,gregexpr("[[:word:]]+",sentence,perl=TRUE)))

         # get the rows of sentiment_DF corresponding to the words in the sentence using match
         # N.B. if a word occurs twice, there will be two equal rows 
         # (but I think it's correct since in this way you count its polarity twice)
         subDF <- sentiment_DF[match(wordsOfASentence,sentiment_DF$word,nomatch = 0),]


         # Find (number) of matching word. 
         wordOfInterest <- wordsOfASentence[which(wordsOfASentence %in% levels(sentiment_DF$word))]  # No multigrepl, so working with duplicates instead. eg interesting
         regexOfInterest <- paste0("([^\\s]+\\s){0,3}", wordOfInterest, "(\\s[^\\s]+){0,3}")

         # extract a context of 3 words before the word in the dataframe
        context <-  stringr::str_extract(sentence, regexOfInterest)
         names(context) <- wordOfInterest  # Helps in forloop

         print(context)
         for(i in 1:length(context)){
             if(any(unlist(strsplit(context[i], " ")) %in% booster_words))

             {
                 print(booster_words)
                 if(any(unlist(strsplit(context[i], " ")) %in% negative_words))

                 {
                     subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity <- subDF$positive.polarity + 4

                 }
                 else 
                 {
                     subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity <- subDF$positive.polarity + 9

                 }
             }
         }



         # Debug option
         print(subDF)

         # calculate the total polarity of the sentence and store in the vector
         polarity[i] <- sum(subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity) - sum(subDF$negative.ponderate.polarity)

    }
     return(polarity)
 }

 sentiment_DF <- data.frame(word=c('interesting','boring','pretty'),
                            positive.polarity=c(1,0,1),
                            negative.polarity=c(0,1,0))
 sentences <- c("The course was interesting, but the professor was not so boring")
 result <- calcPolarity(sentiment_DF,sentences)
```

When I run it with this sentence :

```
"The course was interesting, but the professor was not so boring"
```

I get this result :

```
         word positive.polarity negative.polarity positive.ponderate.polarity
1 interesting                 1                 0                           5
2      boring                 0                 1                           4
```

but this is not correst, 
The correct result is :

```
 word positive.polarity negative.polarity positive.ponderate.polarity
1 interesting                 1                 0                  1
2      boring                 0                 1                  4
```

I do'nt know whey i get incorrect value.. 
Any idea please to help me?

Thank you

**EDIT:**

For example , If i have this dataframe :

```
      word positive.polarity negative.polarity positive.ponderate.polarity   negative.ponderate.polarity
1 interesting                 1                 0                           1        1  
   2      boring                 0                 1                           4      2
```

The result should  be : `(1+4) -(1+2)`

Comment: I can't get same results as yours. The context extracts only 3 chars and not three words (here context gives "o boring"). Maybe your regex is wrong ?

Comment: For me I get contet = [1] "The course was interesting" "was not so boring"   which is correct

Comment: No idea? I don't know why it seems so complicated

Comment: Strange.. no one can help me..

Comment: Shouldn't your expected result be `interesting: 10` and `boring: 0`? `Interesting` starts from 1 and has no negative, so 1 + 9 = 10, and `boring` does not have any booster word to start with

Comment: @GGamba  Concern the word "interesting" in its context, there is no booster-word , so it take the basic value (here 1); concern the word "boring" in its context there are the booster-word "so" and the negative-word "not" so it take the original value + 4 (here 0+4). I don't know if i am clear

Comment: @CyrineEzzahra the corrected code is below, your `subDF$positive.polarity` is variable length depending on the number of `sentiment_DF` words in the sentence, in this case a vector `c(1,0)` and you are adding 4 to both numbers instead on only to the second element.  See explanation in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have caught the error.  In cases like this it is recommended to debug line by line, and to print the initial variable, the result of each if statement or an indicator if the if else statement was processed.

Here your initial `subDF$positive.polarity` is a vector `c(1,0)` of length 2, which is the number of words in sentiment_DF `c("interesting, "boring")`.

when i=1, `context="The course was interesting"`, there is no booster and no negative words -- `subDF$positive.polarity` is `c(1,0)` and `subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity` is `NULL`

when i=2, `context="was not so boring"`, there is a booster and a negative word -- `subDF$positive.polarity` is `c(1,0)` and you are adding 4 to both elements when you want to add 4 to only the second element corresponding to `"boring"`, because of this `subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity` is `c(5,4)` which is what is returned.

The trick here is that length of `subDF$positive.polarity` and `subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity` depends on the number of `sentiment_DF` words in the sentence.  The corrected code and the debugging are below. Here are the fixes:

A. Initialize so as lengths are equal

```
 subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity <- subDF$positive.polarity
```

B. Use i to index so you are adding value only to the element corresponding to the current context element, and not all elements

```
  subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity[i] <- subDF$positive.polarity[i] + 4
  subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity[i] <- subDF$positive.polarity[i] + 9
```

C. There is one thing that I did not fix as I'm not sure how to treat it... what if the context is: "course was so boring"? There is a booster, and no negative words so it passes to else statement and 9 is added.  Is this positive.ponderate.polarity? Wouldn't it be a negative.ponderate.polarity?

```
calcPolarity(sentiment_DF, "The course was so boring")
    word positive.polarity negative.polarity positive.ponderate.polarity
2 boring                 0                 1                           9
```

D. Other cases check out:

```
calcPolarity(sentiment_DF, "The course was interesting, but the professor was not so boring")
         word positive.polarity negative.polarity positive.ponderate.polarity
1 interesting                 1                 0                           1
2      boring                 0                 1                           4

calcPolarity(sentiment_DF, "The course was so interesting")
         word positive.polarity negative.polarity positive.ponderate.polarity
1 interesting                 1                 0                          10
```

Edited to correct result of polarity as in the comment:
The output of polarity is `c(0,5)` as the orig code is: `polarity[i] <- sum(subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity) - sum(subDF$negative.ponderate.polarity)`.  Since you have 2 context phrases, your i at the end is 2, then polarity[1] is your initial value 0, and the result of your sum is assigned to polarity[2] which is 5, leaving you with c(0,5). Instead remove the [i], should be just `polarity <- sum(subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity) -sum(subDF$negative.ponderate.polarity)`

Here is the corrected code:

```
calcPolarity <- function(sentiment_DF,sentences){
  booster_words <- c("more","enough", "a lot", "as", "so")
  negative_words <- c("not", "rien", "ni", "aucun", "nul", "jamais", "pas", "non plus", "sans")
  reduce_words <- c("peu", "presque", "moins", "seulement")
  # pre-allocate the polarity result vector with size = number of sentences
  polarity <- rep.int(0,length(sentences))

  # loop per sentence
  for(i in 1:length(polarity)){
sentence <- sentences[i]

# separate each sentence in words using regular expression 
wordsOfASentence <- unlist(regmatches(sentence,gregexpr("[[:word:]]+",sentence,perl=TRUE)))

# get the rows of sentiment_DF corresponding to the words in the sentence using match
# N.B. if a word occurs twice, there will be two equal rows 
# (but I think it's correct since in this way you count its polarity twice)
subDF <- sentiment_DF[match(wordsOfASentence,sentiment_DF$word,nomatch = 0),]
print(subDF)

# Find (number) of matching word. 
wordOfInterest <- wordsOfASentence[which(wordsOfASentence %in% levels(sentiment_DF$word))]  # No multigrepl, so working with duplicates instead. eg interesting
regexOfInterest <- paste0("([^\\s]+\\s){0,3}", wordOfInterest, "(\\s[^\\s]+){0,3}")

# extract a context of 3 words before the word in the dataframe
context <-  stringr::str_extract(sentence, regexOfInterest)
names(context) <- wordOfInterest  # Helps in forloop

for(i in 1:length(context)){
  print(paste("i:", i))
  print(context)
  print("initial")
  print(subDF$positive.polarity)
  subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity <- subDF$positive.polarity
  print(subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity)

  if (any(unlist(strsplit(context[i], " ")) %in% booster_words)) {
    print(booster_words)
    length(booster_words)
    print("if level 1")
    print(subDF$positive.polarity)
    if (any(unlist(strsplit(context[i], " ")) %in% negative_words)) {
      subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity[i] <- subDF$positive.polarity[i] + 4
      print("if level 2A")
      print(subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity)
    } else {
      print("if level 2B")
      subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity[i] <- subDF$positive.polarity[i] + 9
      print(subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity)
    }

    print("level 2 result")
    print(subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity)
  }
  print("level 1 result")
  print(subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity)

    }
  }
    # Debug option
    print(subDF)

    # calculate the total polarity of the sentence and store in the vector
    polarity <- sum(subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity) - sum(subDF$negative.ponderate.polarity)

  return(polarity)
}

sentiment_DF <- data.frame(word=c('interesting','boring','pretty'),
                       positive.polarity=c(1,0,1),
                       negative.polarity=c(0,1,0))
calcPolarity(sentiment_DF, "The course was interesting, but the professor was not so boring")
calcPolarity(sentiment_DF, "The course was so interesting")
calcPolarity(sentiment_DF, "The course was so boring")
```

Comment: thank you very much for the time you take to response me, but I still have a question : why when I did "calcPolarity(sentiment_DF, "The course was interesting, but the professor was not so boring")"   I get  "0 5" as result. I have only 1 sentence, so I shoul only 1 value ?

Comment: This is the output of polarity correct?  This is your code: `polarity[i] <- sum(subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity) -sum(subDF$negative.ponderate.polarity)`, you have 2 context phrases so your i at the end is 2, then polarity[1] is your initial, and the result of your sum is assigned to polarity[2] which I believe is 5, leaving you with c(0,5).  Instead remove the [i], should be just `polarity <- sum(subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity) -sum(subDF$negative.ponderate.polarity)`

Comment: I edit my post, please see the example to see how I determine polarity

Comment: I understood it.  See my comment C. In your code you never assign negative.ponderate.polarity, this variable only appears at the end and not seen elsewhere.  That is why I asked comment C.  Currently you only have (1+4) - 0 = 5.

Comment: Ok, I will add the code concernthe  negative.ponderate.polarity column

Comment: Please consider my comment C, and the case I indicated there.  You cannot leave that else statement as is, it needs another qualifier or else "so boring" will get assigned positive.ponderate.polarity points.   I will leave this to you, and consider the question answered. You can send a comment if you need, and please accept the answer so this can be marked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136967/discussion-between-cyrine-ezzahra-and-r-s).

Comment: Last question please : why when I run the script with "calcPolarity(sentiment_DF, sentences <- c("The course was so interesting, but the professor was so boring.",
                                "stackoverflow is an interesting place with interesting people!"))"     I get only one polarity.  I have 2 sentences, so I should have 2 polarities

Comment: In short the number of polarities result is equal to the number of sentence. for each sentence we determine its polarity